# Javascript not running in browser, but works in JSFiddle and some other html editors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote this simple code which takes in parameters from the database Caspio to create a simple table. I just want this table to 1. remove all fields which are empty (not filled out by user) and 2. have alternating colored rows to make it easier to see. I've looked through the other forums but I can't find a good solution (I'm new to JS).The code works in JSFiddle as well as a couple of other html editors, but not all and it doesn't work when I implement it. Does anyone see the issue? I've attached all my code. Just the Javascript file, there are no other attachments.

https://jsfiddle.net/c0yoat51/

```
    <table cellpadding="10" class="Form" BORDER="5" WIDTH="95%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">&nbsp;
        <h3>[@field:TestOrder] - [@field:Facility]</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="250" />
    <col width="750" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>FIELD</th>
      <th>RESPONSE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Facility :</td>
      <td>[@field:Facility]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Patient ID :</td>
      <td>[@field:PatientID]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>First Name :</td>
      <td>[@field:PatientFirst]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Last Name :</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Date of Birth:</td>
      <td>[@field:DateOfBirth]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Gender :</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Primary Phone :</td>
      <td>[@field:PrimaryPhone]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Secondary Phone :</td>
      <td>[@field:SecondaryPhone]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Emergency Contact :</td>
      <td>[@field:EmergencyContact]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Emergency Number :</td>
      <td>[@field:EmergencyNumber]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Patient Address :</td>
      <td>[@field:PatientAddress]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>City :</td>
      <td>[@field:City]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>State :</td>
      <td>[@field:State ]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Zip Code :</td>
      <td>[@field:ZipCode]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Special Instructions :</td>
      <td>[@field:SpecialInstructions]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Primary Insurance :</td>
      <td>[@field:PrimaryInsurance]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Primary Subscriber ID :</td>
      <td>[@field:PrimarySubscriberID]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Primary Subscriber Relationship :</td>
      <td>[@field:PrmarySubscriberRelationship]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Secondary Insurance :</td>
      <td>[@field:SecondaryInsurance ]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Secondary Insurance ID :</td>
      <td>[@field:SecondaryInsuranceID ]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Secondary Subscriber Relationship :</td>
      <td>[@field:SecondarySubscriberRelationship ]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Diagnosis :</td>
      <td>[@field:Diagnosis]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Other Diagnosis :</td>
      <td>[@field:OtherDiagnosis]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Physician Name :</td>
      <td>[@field:PhysicianName ]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Other Physician :</td>
      <td>[@field:OtherPhysician]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Physician Phone :</td>
      <td>[@field:PhysicianPhone]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Physician Fax :</td>
      <td>[@field:PhysicianFax]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>After Hours Phone :</td>
      <td>[@field:AfterHoursPhone]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Test Order :</td>
      <td>[@field:TestOrder]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Test Duration :</td>
      <td>[@field:TestDuration]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Holter Performed :</td>
      <td>[@field:HolterPerformed]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Holter Test Order :</td>
      <td>[@field:HolterTestOrder]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Holter Duration :</td>
      <td>[@field:HolterDuration]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Previous Holter Date :</td>
      <td>[@field:PreviousHolterDate]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Requested Start Date :</td>
      <td>[@field:RequestedStartDate]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Receive Monitor :</td>
      <td>[@field:ReceiveMonitor]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Recorder ID Number :</td>
      <td>[@field:RecorderIDNumber ]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>H_P :</td>
      <td>[@field:H_P]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Upload HP :</td>
      <td>[@field:UpploadHP]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Authorize :</td>
      <td>[@field:Authorize]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="LEFT">
      <td>Submit :</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.Form tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td:eq(1):empty').length > 0;
  }).hide();

</script>
<style type="text/css">
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #D3D3D3
  }

</style>
```

Please help, and thanks!

All the javascript code is at the bottom, the rest is just making the table

So the same code, copied and pasted won't be working at https://html-online.com/editor/

Comment: "Code needed to submit, but please just look at jsfiddle file?"  Please don't do that. You need to include code in the question because you're *supposed to include the code in the question.* [ask] [mcve]

Comment: your js fiddle also not working .because its not have any empty element

Comment: Sorry, I inserted the code. The JS Fiddle is hiding the "Gender", "Last Name" and "Submit" fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need  apply your code with in [`document.ready`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiyjI7NkbHUAhVLQI8KHZXECgMQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.jquery.com%2Fusing-jquery-core%2Fdocument-ready%2F&usg=AFQjCNExWbD0RBCnOOUMXHiJCRB_nNuJJw&sig2=eK-p3rlOHsqxUkKV73o62g) .It will run only window after load.`nbsp;` not select from `:empty` .you need to `trim()` .Then only get the empty space `td` also .`!` matching the empty element of `td`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.Form').find('tbody tr').filter(function() {
        return !$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().trim()
      }).hide()
    })
```

**Updated**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Nisha Jewellery</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.Form').find('tbody tr').filter(function() {
        return !$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().trim()
      }).hide()
    })
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #D3D3D3
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="Form" border="5" width="95%" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;
          <h3>[@field:TestOrder] - [@field:Facility]</h3>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <colgroup>
      <col width="250" />
      <col width="750" /> </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>FIELD</th>
        <th>RESPONSE</th>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Facility :</td>
        <td>[@field:Facility]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Patient ID :</td>
        <td>[@field:PatientID]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>First Name :</td>
        <td>[@field:PatientFirst]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Last Name :</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Date of Birth:</td>
        <td>[@field:DateOfBirth]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Gender :</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Primary Phone :</td>
        <td>[@field:PrimaryPhone]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Secondary Phone :</td>
        <td>[@field:SecondaryPhone]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Emergency Contact :</td>
        <td>[@field:EmergencyContact]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Emergency Number :</td>
        <td>[@field:EmergencyNumber]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Patient Address :</td>
        <td>[@field:PatientAddress]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>City :</td>
        <td>[@field:City]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>State :</td>
        <td>[@field:State ]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Zip Code :</td>
        <td>[@field:ZipCode]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Special Instructions :</td>
        <td>[@field:SpecialInstructions]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Primary Insurance :</td>
        <td>[@field:PrimaryInsurance]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Primary Subscriber ID :</td>
        <td>[@field:PrimarySubscriberID]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Primary Subscriber Relationship :</td>
        <td>[@field:PrmarySubscriberRelationship]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Secondary Insurance :</td>
        <td>[@field:SecondaryInsurance ]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Secondary Insurance ID :</td>
        <td>[@field:SecondaryInsuranceID ]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Secondary Subscriber Relationship :</td>
        <td>[@field:SecondarySubscriberRelationship ]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Diagnosis :</td>
        <td>[@field:Diagnosis]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Other Diagnosis :</td>
        <td>[@field:OtherDiagnosis]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Physician Name :</td>
        <td>[@field:PhysicianName ]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Other Physician :</td>
        <td>[@field:OtherPhysician]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Physician Phone :</td>
        <td>[@field:PhysicianPhone]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Physician Fax :</td>
        <td>[@field:PhysicianFax]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>After Hours Phone :</td>
        <td>[@field:AfterHoursPhone]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Test Order :</td>
        <td>[@field:TestOrder]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Test Duration :</td>
        <td>[@field:TestDuration]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Holter Performed :</td>
        <td>[@field:HolterPerformed]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Holter Test Order :</td>
        <td>[@field:HolterTestOrder]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Holter Duration :</td>
        <td>[@field:HolterDuration]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Previous Holter Date :</td>
        <td>[@field:PreviousHolterDate]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Requested Start Date :</td>
        <td>[@field:RequestedStartDate]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Receive Monitor :</td>
        <td>[@field:ReceiveMonitor]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Recorder ID Number :</td>
        <td>[@field:RecorderIDNumber ]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>H_P :</td>
        <td>[@field:H_P]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Upload HP :</td>
        <td>[@field:UpploadHP]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Authorize :</td>
        <td>[@field:Authorize]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="LEFT">
        <td>Submit :</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Is there any way you could put that in a jsfiddle and post that because it works but since I'm new to javascript, I don't exactly know what to put in the html to get it to run where I want. But the code works!! I don't have a CSS part, just purely html. Thanks again

Comment: @DavidHo see my updated answer.i was added with single file js html and css